# Play and pause functions works only once

Tags: live-streaming

I'm viewing the live streams using the flash player. while i'm doing that i have tried to play and pause the streams using the following function but it is only works for only one click. if i'm re-clicking it does not shows any changes. If you realize my problem. please suggest me.

```
function testPause(event:MouseEvent) {  
    nsPlay.pause(); 
}

function testPlay(event:MouseEvent) {
    if(!bolLoaded) {
        nsPlay.play(streamValue);
        bolLoaded = true;
    } else {
        nsPlay.resume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make Boolean variable value FALSE in pause state.**

```
bolLoaded = false;
```